# Replace a picture on a slide in PowerPoint using VSTO

Tags: c#, office365, powerpoint, vsto, office-interop

Is it possible to use this built-in feature from C#?

[image]

I'd like to use this programmatically. I've already put an image in the clipboard.

I've looked through the `Shape` object, but couldn't find any methods to do this.

Some information:

VSTO Add-in for PowerPoint

.NET 4.8

Answer (score 1):

Sence I am not using 365, there is no function like yours in my pop-up menu. I don't know if there is such a mechanism that can be applied in VBA or even in .NET.

I can figure out 3 ways to add a picture in a slide now, and 2 of them are associated with clipboard. You can try my code first.

```cs
        private void Replace_a_picture_on_a_slide_in_PowerPoint_using_VSTO()
        {
            string fFullName = "A:\\Users\\oscar\\Dropbox\\VS\\VBA\\stackoverflow.pptm";


            string pFullName = @"A:\Users\oscar\Dropbox\test\DSC00725.jpg";//the value just for test


            //open pptm file and set the Presentation variable
            Presentation presentation = Application.Presentations.Open(fFullName);
            //or
            //Presentation presentation = Application.ActivePresentation;

            // get the slide 
            Slide slide = presentation.Slides[1];

            // get the pic on the slide
            Shape sp = slide.Shapes[1];

            if (sp.Type == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoPicture)
            // replace with the pic
            { // sp.Fill.UserPicture(pFullName);

                //You have to chose only one below to check out', or use Break() to check them step by step if you can

                //1
                sp = Replace_a_picture_on_a_slide_from_pic_file_name(slide, sp, pFullName);
                //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

                //2
                sp = Replace_a_picture_on_a_slide_from_Clipboard_Directly(slide, sp);
                //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

                //3
                sp = Replace_a_picture_on_a_slide_from_Clipboard(pFullName, slide, sp);
                //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }


            // save PowerPoint file if need
            //presentation.Save();

        }

        private static Shape Replace_a_picture_on_a_slide_from_Clipboard(string pFullName, Slide slide, Shape sp)
        {
            var image = Clipboard.GetImage();
            if (image != null)
            {
                var outputPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "tempImage.png");
                //var outputPath = Path.Combine("x:\\", "tempImage.png");//for test
                pFullName = outputPath;
                image.Save(outputPath, ImageFormat.Png);
                //PowerPoint.Shape shape = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange[1];
                //shape.Fill.UserPicture(outputPath);
                slide.Shapes.AddPicture(pFullName, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, sp.Left, sp.Top, sp.Width, sp.Height);
                sp.Delete();
                
            }
            return (slide.Shapes[slide.Shapes.Count]);
        }

        private static Shape Replace_a_picture_on_a_slide_from_Clipboard_Directly(Slide slide, Shape sp)
        {
            int spCount = slide.Shapes.Count;
            //Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWindow.View.PasteSpecial();
            slide.Shapes.Paste();
            if (spCount < slide.Shapes.Count)
            {
                Shape spNew = slide.Shapes[slide.Shapes.Count];
                spNew.Left = sp.Left;
                spNew.Top = sp.Top;
                spNew.Width = sp.Width;
                spNew.Height = sp.Height;
                sp.Delete();
            }
            return (slide.Shapes[slide.Shapes.Count]);
        }

        Shape Replace_a_picture_on_a_slide_from_pic_file_name(Slide slide, Shape sp, string pFullName)
        {
            // SaveWithDocument : This argument must be msoTrue if LinkToFile is msoFalse. 'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.shapes.addpicture
            slide.Shapes.AddPicture(pFullName, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue, sp.Left, sp.Top, sp.Width, sp.Height);
            sp.Delete();
            return (slide.Shapes[slide.Shapes.Count]);
        }
```

Shall be they what you want? If they are luckily Yes, then which one is your favorite? tell me, and I guess the `Replace_a_picture_on_a_slide_from_Clipboard_Directly`, because me too.

Comment: The "change picture" feature in 365 copies all styles, animations, size changes, etc to the new image. I have implemented my own solution that copies this. Thank you though!